# jquery can't find selected value

Tags: jquery

jQuery is behaving very strangely in a script. Basically, after updating the DOM using jquery I am trying to get the value of a file input that has been inserted into the DOM using the ID. But if I try to access the file element directly I get an empty string. However if I try to access the file by starting at the parent div I get the correct value. Unfortunately I need to access it directly:

```
alert($("#input_id").val()); //returns empty string
alert($("#div_id > #input_id").val()); //returns correct value.
```

Comment: Do you for some reason have more elements with that same ID on your page, inserted or not ?

Comment: Please reproduce that with a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

you have duplicate ID in the document, try to make the ID unique.
As jQuery documentation said,
If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM

Comment: I don't think I have a duplicate id. To test this I tried $("#input_id").each (function () {alert(this);});  which only provided one alert.

Comment: given there is no info about the html a down vote of this is stupid this is actualy a solution. check this out http://jsfiddle.net/8X2Xq/

Comment: Also if you check the fiddle out $("#input_id").each(function(){ alert("!"); });​​​​​​​​​​​ this only gives one alert despite having 4 of the same ID that is because when searching for ID jQ is happy with the first thing it finds

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have double id's some where check my fiddle out to see that what you said earlier about each function does not prove you don't have duplicate id's. The best way to find duplicates is to do a search or maby a grep if you are on linux like systems.

```
find . | xargs grep "input_id"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8X2Xq/1/

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by **Pablo Karlsson** I believe there might be multiple elements with same id, hence jquery had failed to identify value of element using it's id.

If you are planning to access the element value directly, why can't you use class name specific selector in jquery(If you have any class name has applied to your input element).